# Service Wrapper => Service Pattern best practices

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, domain-driven-design

I am build a enterprise level web api from the ground up, I have around 12 services and a entity framework repo wrapper.

Basically after a refactor of my web api, I realised I was passing 9 services into the controller via IOC.

So I have created a service wrapper for all my services:

```
public class ServiceWrapper : IServiceWrapper
    {
        public ServiceWrapper(ILoggerManager loggerManager, IRepositoryWrapper repositoryWrapper, IAuditLog auditLog, IConfiguration config, ICsvImporter csvImporter, IEmailService emailService, IEmailTemplate emailTemplate, IEmailConfiguration emailConfig, IEncoreService encoreService, IUserService userService, ISQLClient sqlClient, IDocumentService documentService)
        {
            LoggerManager = loggerManager;
            RepositoryWrapper = repositoryWrapper;
            AuditLog = auditLog;
            Config = config;
            CsvImporter = csvImporter;
            EmailService = emailService;
            EmailTemplate = emailTemplate;
            EncoreService = encoreService;
            UserService = userService;
            EmailConfiguration = emailConfig;
            SqlClient = sqlClient;
            DocumentService = documentService;
        }

        public ILoggerManager LoggerManager { get; set; }       
        public IRepositoryWrapper RepositoryWrapper { get; set; }
        public IAuditLog AuditLog { get; set; }
        public IConfiguration Config { get; set; }
        public ICsvImporter CsvImporter { get; set; }
        public IEmailService EmailService { get; set; }
        public IEmailConfiguration EmailConfiguration { get; set; }
        public IEmailTemplate EmailTemplate { get; set; }
        public IEncoreService EncoreService { get; set; }
        public IUserService UserService { get; set; }
        public ISQLClient SqlClient { get; set; }
        public IDocumentService DocumentService { get; set; }
    }
```

My question really, is this best practice, or is there a better way, I want to stay with domain driven architecture, IOC and service patterns.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at `MediatR` by Jimmy Bogard. You can divide your actions into commands and queries and use only the necessary services there. It uses the CQRS pattern.

Comment: The mediator pattern does look like the next step. I'll probably have to read more on this, as I have to help explain this to junior devs.

Answer (score 1):

The service wrapper is very ineffective as your app instantiate all the services on every api call, even if these services won't be used.

To reduce amount of services passed via constructor or api methods signatures you can pass IService provider and use [GetService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceproviderserviceextensions.getservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) extension method.

In this case you will be able to instantiate only the necessary services when you'll need it.

In most cases the code won't be more compex than with service wrapper.
If it won't be sufficient you can update your wrapper in following way:

```
public class ServiceWrapper : IServiceWrapper
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    public ServiceWrapper(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }
    
    public ILoggerManager LoggerManager { get { return _serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerManager>(); }} // store GetService result in a local property if it will be necessary for reuse.
    ....

}
```

But I don't recommend this approach as it increase components coupling and may reduce app maintainability in the future.

Comment: My services use different services, i've tried to keep each service to it's domain, for example logging, audit, user, csv, sqlclient services might be used in the encoreService which is business logic, and the repositoryService is used in all the business services.

Services depend on services in a way, and the wrapper is all the services in that bunch.

Comment: The service wrapper is not very effective. You are instantiating all the services even in case if it is not necessary. In case if your services are singleton's it makes solves problem but it will mean that you will have to pass non-singleton services sepaately.

Comment: They are all "Transient" and Yes, I am aware this is not the most efficient, however a lot of those services are inter reliant, e.g. audit, logging, repository, email are all used.

I have tried to maintain the "single use principle" but this has inadvertently created a sh!t load of services.

Comment: @IanJowett As an alternative you can pass single IServiceProvider and use GetService extension method. It will reduce amount of sevices which should be passed and it will be cleaner way as only necessary services will be instantiated.

Comment: Updated my answer to better fit to the problem which you are trying to solve.